# Next.js Static Nested Dynamic Routing with nested iteration

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js, url-routing, supabase

Suppose you have `posts` and `categories` data from a relation database:

```js
// category_id on categories.id
const posts = [
  { id: '1', title: 'dream pc', category_id: '1' },
  { id: '2', title: 'my dream house design', category_id: '1' },
  { id: '3', title: 'bing chillin', category_id: '2' },
]

const categories = [
  { id: '1', name: 'wishlist' }, 
  { id: '2', name: 'favorites' }
]
```

This is my route format: `/categories/[category]/[page]`

With directory structure of `pages/categories/[category]/[page].js`.

So it will produce these paths:

- `/categories/wishlist/1`
- `/categories/wishlist/2`
- `/categories/favorites/1`

I've tried this but `paths` returned an empty array:

```js
// pages/categories/[category]/[page].js

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = []

    // I'm using supabase
    const { data: categories, error } = await supabase.from('categories').select('id, name')

    categories.forEach(async (c) => {
        const { data, error, count } = await supabase
            .from('posts')
            .select('id', { count: 'exact', head: true })
            .eq('category_id', c.id)

        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // This should push the path params to the paths variable, but it didn't
            paths.push({
                params: {
                    // For simplicity, 1 post per page
                    page: i + 1,
                    categoryId: c.id,
                    category: c.name
                }
            })
        }
    })

    // It returns an empty array []
    console.log(paths)

    return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the expected data from the supabase's requests? If `categories` is empty that would explain why you're getting an empty `paths` array.

Comment: Of course, I have my data on supabase

Comment: If you log `count` to the console, does it return the expected value on each `forEach` iteration?

Comment: @juliomalves yes it is, the count exists

Comment: hmm, when I replace that supabase data, it seems to work with regular array. let me investigate more

Comment: @juliomalves Strange things happens, `console.log(paths)` on the bottom most seems to called first, then `console.log` inside `forEach` is called later. I think there is a problem with the async calling

Comment: Got it, should've use for/of instead of forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async calling does not work with `Array.forEach`, instead I use `for (category of categories)`

Working code:

```js
// pages/categories/[category]/[page].js

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = []

    // I'm using supabase
    const { data: categories, error } = await supabase.from('categories').select('id, name')

    // Use for/of instead of forEach
    for (category of categories) {
        const { data, error, count } = await supabase
            .from('posts')
            .select('id', { count: 'exact', head: true })
            .eq('category_id', c.id)

        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            paths.push({
                params: {
                    page: (i + 1).toString(),
                    categoryId: category.id,
                    category: category.name
                }
            })
        }
    })

    return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```